# Was heißt „Trennkörper“ in einer Patentschrift?

Tags: meaning-in-context, german-to-english, technical-terminology

Ich lese [die Patentschrift Nummer 458392](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lml6eqdlbg5nbp/DE000000458392A_all_pages.pdf?dl=0). Das Wort *Trennkörper* kommt dort vor, aber ich verstehe dessen Bedeutung nicht. Google Translate sagt, das sei ein „separating body“. Ist das technisch korrekt?
Ein ähnliches Wort in einem ähnlichen Patent auf Englisch ist „separating plate“. Ist das richtig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In der Patentschrift ist von zwei Trennkörpern die Rede, die beide den Stromfluss unterbinden. Einer wird für das Ausschalten verwendet, der zweite tritt bei Überlastung des Stromkreises in Aktion, indem er das Einschalten verhindert.

Als Übersetzung scheint mir *separating object* angemessen oder *separating part*.

Comment: Die Aufgabe der Trennkörper ist es den Schaltlichtbogen zu löschen und nicht an sich den Stromfluss zu unterbrechen.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Warum Lichtbogen? In der Patentschrift heißt es, die Kontakte sind durch Federn aneinander gepresst, und der Trennkörper schiebt sich dazwischen, drückt sie auseinander.

Comment: Um den Strom zu unterbrechen, reicht es im Prinzip die Kontakte auseinander zu bewegen (wie auch immer). Wenn hohe Ströme geschaltet werden, kann aber beim Trennen der Kontakte einen Lichtbogen in der Luft zwischen den Kontakten entstehen. Eine Möglichkeit den Lichtbogen zu vermeiden oder schnell zu löschen ist halt einen Trennkörper zwischen die Kontakte zu schieben. Für die Unterbrechung vom Stromfluss an sich (abgesehen vom möglichen Lichtbogen) ist der Trennkörper aber nicht notwendig.